# Ngrx mergeMap inside catchError to join more actions get me error

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to dispatch two actions
inside a catchError block
but I've got this error

> Argument of type '(error: {}) => void' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type '(value: {}, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'. Type
>   'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { catchError, map, mergeMap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import {
  AuthenticationAccount
} from '../../models/account.model';

import * as fromActions from '../actions';

import { ACCOUNT_SERVICE } from '../../tokens';

@Injectable()
export class AccountEffects {
  @Effect()
  account$ = this.actions$.ofType(fromActions.ACCOUNT)
    .pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.accountService.account()
        .pipe(
        map((account: AuthenticationAccount) => {
          return { type: fromActions.ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, payload: account };
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
          return mergeMap((error) => {
            [{ type: fromActions.ACCOUNT_FAIL, payload: error },
            { type: fromActions.LOGIN_RESET}]
          })
        })
        )
    })
    );
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(ACCOUNT_SERVICE) private accountService
  ) { }
}
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: SO should add a rule when there is a downvote should be a reason ^^

Comment: I personally downvoted as I consider the title of your question to not be appropriate; describe your issue with your own words, dont copy-paste your error log in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `catchError` section is wrong, you are using `mergeMap` as a static method, but outside of the `pipe` scope, which is not possible.

Rework it as follows:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from':

catchError((error) => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
          const actions = [{ type: fromActions.ACCOUNT_FAIL, payload: error }, { type: fromActions.LOGIN_RESET}];
          return from(actions);
        })
```

BTW:

- Why are you injecting a service using a token?
- Why don't you use action creators? Instead of creating new objects you could use classes or methods to generate those.

Comment: "Why are you injecting a service using a token?" I think its a best practice or not? "Why don't you use action creators? Instead of creating new objects you could use classes or methods to generate those." sorry I don't see the point. Can you make me an example? I find dispatch actions with plain object easier than use class

Comment: What makes you think its a best practice to use tokens? Normally the token of a service class is the class itself.

Comment: Manually creating (untyped) plain objects is totally error prone. A lot of the code in the scope of the effect isnt strongly typed, because of that something like { typ: fromActions.ACCOUNT_FAIL, payload: error } or { type: fromActions.ACCOUNT_FAIL, paylad: error } (notice the typos) could easily go unnoticed. If you capsulate this "factory" logic in classes or pure functions, is harder to cause problems of this type.

Comment: "What makes you think its a best practice to use tokens?" you don't have name collision problem

Comment: BTW I regret the chaining :) pipe is good for the bundle but its a little messy ^^

Comment: I simplified my answer, please check if still works as expected